# cURL request not working on localhost and no error

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I use php 7.* on my wamp server, each time i make a curl request it does not return any results or show error. I can't figure out the problem. The same code works fine on live server. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your php/php.ini file

Search for extension=php_curl.dll and remove the comment.

Restart